# Add dynamic library to firebreath

Tags: macos, cmake, firebreath

I'm developing a plugin for mac. I'm trying to use afnetworking and other frameworks which needs arc. I'm trying to create a .a(library) for the framework and access it in firebreath. I tried adding the directory which contains .a using include_directories in projectdef.cmake then linking it in target_link_libraries. Please lemme know how to add this and whether the framework can be used in firebreath without any pitfalls

Answer (score 0):

I have used external libraries in firebreath. Though I have used editors to link the libraries. You need to specify .h files for the function prototypes, along with .a files which will dynamically link to .dylib

Try adding these via Xcode and see if that works.

Comment: i have added the .h files and .dylib to project source files. I get a error that .dylib not found. How did you add it via Xcode I can't find any option of link libraries in xcode firebreath project, or i guess i might not be looking in the right place.

Comment: You also have to add .a file in XCode.
.h files will help your code compile.
.a files will help link your code. you have to add .a files as linker files.
.dylib file should be in system lib include folder which is generally in your bash path.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have given the link of header files in library to header search path of the project and added .a as target. It worked